# Find elements of specific type in single table inheritance type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria, criteria-api

Imagine the following Entity hierarchy:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", columnDefinition = "varchar(60)")
abstract class Resource {

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("resource1")
class Resource1 extends Resource {
  @Embedded
  private Property property1;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("resource2")
class Resource2 extends Resource {
  @Embedded
  private Property property2;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("resource3")
class Resource3 extends Resource {
  @Embedded
  private Property property3;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("resource4")
class Resource4 extends Resource {
  @Embedded
  private Property property4;
}

@Entity
class EntityUsingResource {
  @OneToMany(...)
  @JoinColumn(...)
  private List<Resource> resources;
}
```

I am trying to create a UI to search for `EntityUsingResource`s and being able to filter for elements that have resources with a specific property.

So in the search field in the GUI you can type a value for lets say `property4` and it filters all `EntityUsingResource`s which have a resource of type `Resource4` whos property4 equals the one you typed in.

So far I managed to do this by using this criteria api using springs specifications:

```
public static Specification<EntityUsingResource> 
withResource4HavingProperty4Like(String property4) {
    Join<EntityUsingResource, Resource> join = 
        root.join(EntityUsingResource_.resources, JoinType.INNER);
    Join<EntityUsingResource, Resource4> treatedJoin = 
      cb.treat(join, Resource4.class);

    return cb.like(
            treatedJoin.get(Resource4_.property4).get(Property_.value), 
            "%" + property4 + "%");
}

public static Specification<EntityUsingResource> 
withResource2HavingProperty2Like(String property2) {
    Join<EntityUsingResource, Resource> join = 
        root.join(EntityUsingResource_.resources, JoinType.INNER);
    Join<EntityUsingResource, Resource2> treatedJoin = 
        cb.treat(join, Resource2.class);

    return cb.like(
        treatedJoin.get(Resource2_.property2).get(Property_.value),
        "%" + property2 + "%");
}
```

I use those specifications with springs Specifications utility class as follows:
    where(
        withResource2HavingProperty2Like(property2)
    ).and(
        withResource4HavingProperty4Like(property4)
    );

Which I then pass to the `JpaRepository` and more or less return the result to the gui.

This creates the following SQL when searching for property1:

```
select 
    entity_using_resource0.id as entityId
from 
    entity_using_resource entity_using_resource0
inner join resource resourceas1_ on 
    entity_using_resource0.id=resourceas1_.entity_using_resource_id
inner join resource resourceas2_ on 
    entity_using_resource0.id=resourceas2_.entity_using_resource_id
inner join resource resourceas3_ on 
    entity_using_resource0.id=resourceas3_.entity_using_resource_id
inner join resource resourceas4_ on 
    entity_using_resource0.id=resourceas4_.entity_using_resource_id
where (resourceas4_.property1 like 'property1')
    and (resourceas2_.property1 like '%property1%') limit ...;
```

The problem is, this query produces a lot of duplicates. I tried using distinct which would solve the problem, but it raises another. In the `EntityUsingResource` entity I have a column which is of type json so using distinct won't work, as the database can't compare json values.

How would one write a query that also filters for the type of `Resource` using the criteria api?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is creating an effective query rather than using criteria API, you may use [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

(`property2` argument is automatically captured and passed as a parameter)

```java
public List<EntityUsingResource > findEntitiesUsingResource2(String property2) {

    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((EntityUsingResource entity) -> {

        List<Long> resourceIds = subQuery((Resource res) -> {

            SELECT(res.getEntityUsingResource().getId());
            FROM(res);
            WHERE(typeOf(res, Resource2.class) &&
              ((Resource2) res).getProperty2().getValue().matches("%" + property2 + "%"));
        });

        SELECT(entity);
        FROM(entity);
        WHERE(resourceIds.contains(entity.getId()));
    });

    return query.createQuery(em, EntityUsingResource.class).getResultList();
}
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM entity_using_resource t0
WHERE (t0.id IN (SELECT t1.entity_id
FROM resource t1
WHERE (t1.type = 'resource2' AND (t1.property2 LIKE  CONCAT( CONCAT( '%' ,  ?1 ) ,  '%' )  ))) )
```

Support of JPA inheritance is documented [here](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/JPA-Integration#inheritance--table-split).

Comment: I will mark it as the solution although I didn't try it yet. I will give feedback as soon as I tried it. Thanks for your help!